# Java regex can only use 1 quantifier in a lookback (need 2)

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I can't use more then 1 quantifier in a lookback.

The regex I made needs to do the following:
- **1d** test --> remove 1d and leave 'test'
- test **1d** --> remove 1d and leave 'test'
- **1d** test 1d --> remove first 1d and leave 'test 1d'

The regex I want that doesn't work:

```
String string = "11d test 1d";

String[] parts = 
          string.split("(^\\d+[a-zA-Z]\\s)|(\\s\\d+[a-zA-Z]$(?<!^\\d+[a-zA-Z]\\s.*))");
```

OUTPUT:

```
test
```

The regex that does work(but only for a fixed length string, counting the dots):

```
String string = "11d test 1d";

String[] parts = 
         string.split("(^\d+[a-zA-Z]\s)|(\s\d+[a-zA-Z]$(?<!^\d+[a-zA-Z]\s.......))");
```

OUTPUT:

```
test 1d
```

The two quantifiers (in the lookback) are +(after the \d) and *(after the \s)

If you want to test it your self you can past it in https://regex101.com/

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: You give an empty link, do CTRL+S then coy the specific link (besure it's not only the website name)

Comment: have you tried with replaceFirst..? string1.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote("1d"), "");

Comment: @NuthanKumar That works, thanks so much. That I didn't think of that :facepalm: (I did use my own expression instead of `Pattern.quote("1d")` because it works with more then just a **1** and a **d**)

Comment: So, you want to remove the first `<1+ digits><1+ letters>`? Then you need `str.replaceFirst("\\s*\\d+\\p{Alpha}+", "")`. If that word must be a whole word, use `"\\s*\\b\\d+\\p{Alpha}+\\b"`

Comment: @Banjer_HD, I will post it as the answer and please accept it

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for replying! but I want to replace the first `[START]<1+ digits> <1 letter> <space>` OR `<space> <1+ digits> <1 letter>[END]` I think my regex works like that the way it is already (but need to test a little more) c:

Comment: So, `s.replaceFirst("^\\s*\\d+\\p{Alpha}\\b\\s*|\\s+\\d+\\p{Alpha}$", "")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with replaceFirst()?

```
string1.replaceFirst("(^\d+[a-zA-Z]\s)|(\s\d+[a-zA-Z]$)", "");
```